# Filter viewpanel for logged in user

Tags: javascript, filter, view, xpages

I am working an a task manager web application with xpages.I have a viewpanel that showing assigned tasks of all the employees.The administrator of the application can see all assigned tasks.

However each user of the application (employee) must only see the tasks which are attributed to him .I would like to know how to make visible to the logged in user only the tasks which are attributed to him.Is there another solution different from filtering the view by category(employee category)?

Because this solution will require me to create two viewpanels, one for the administrator and the other one categorized for employees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view panel, there is a "Filter by Category Name", where you can just show the items for the current user.  You can obtain the username in SSJS by the Global "session' object.  Before using this, you will need to create a categorized view which you might already have.

You could make it so that an administrator sees all categories, or carry on with a different view panel only visible to administrators.

Comment: Thanks for your answer .But if the administrator is connected, he must see all tasks of all employees.Therefore I would be forced to create a categorized viewpanel that will be visible by employee in there access and another non-categorized and so visible to the administrator.The problem is that I have several viewpanels, so I would have to create in each of my xpages a viewpanel categorized for employees and another non-categorized for the administrator?

Comment: Create each view panel in a custom control, and only show the employee  one to employees, and the administrator one to administrators.  If you need to change them, you change them once and it affects all xpages you use them on.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply, but I have not only a single viewpanel to display, I have several viewpanels and each is one categorized in a way.So I have to create views for the administrator, and categorized views for the employee.That will double all work and consume much more ressources.Is there a simpler solution? for example can i do it by adding a reader or author field when assigning a task to an employee to make him see only his assigned tasks?

Comment: You can add author and reader fields if you want, I personally wouldn't, but they do work.   Otherwise, I am not sure what else to tell you that I haven't already.

Comment: The filter by category value can be computed, so you could show a dropdown list with all users in the system if it is the admin and compute it fixed for the rest. This would open your app for an improvement: let users specify in their profile who else can see their tasks. If they have delegates show the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a role for the admin I can think of two approaches.

1. Would be to create a combo box, hide that combo box unless you are a member of that role, then use the combo box to choose if you want to filter by the username or everything.
2. Would be to compute the category filter on the view to show everything if you are a member of the admin role and filter by username if you are not.

Answer (score 0):

Category in your view can be multivalue, for example:

```
Assignee : "*"
```

Category property of datasource can be computed based on role:

```
return isAdmin() ? "*" : username;
```